# Which ScrollMagic features to implement for a parallax, pin, overlap effect between items?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm trying to figure out what I need to do to accomplish the following:

1. Parallax scroll an image up - i.e., the image scrolls up faster than the rest of the page and overlaps halfway into a div.
2. Pin the image to a point on the page so it stops moving (*not* to the top of the window, which is what I keep finding for overlap parallax effects using fixed positioning).
3. Parallax up a new image that overlaps the first.

I managed to get an overlap effect with by repositioning the pins and triggers in the [Simple Pinning demo](https://scrollmagic.io/examples/basic/simple_pinning.html), but I don't know how to apply the proper parallax effect to the first item so that it goes up first before pinning.